# How to set NTLM authentication in rest template Header in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, ntlm

I want to authenticate NTLM using Rest template , can any one suggest the way ?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone stumble upon this entry again, this is the builtin solution:

Ensure your project includes the `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient`.

Then you can build your RestTemplate with this snippet:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(user, password, "source-host-name", "domain-name"));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work. The 3rd argument in NTCredrntials constructor is called “workstation”. Not sure what will go in there. I just passed null. It throws 401 unauthorised when I do a restTemplate.exchange on the url which means the credentials are not recognised. The same setup works in postman.

Comment: @saran3h As the code above states, you need to send the hostname of the machine doing the request.  See: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/NTCredentials.html#NTCredentials(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

this is what I did taking cues from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840639/spring-rest-template-with-http-client-for-ntlm-authentication). Credits goes here only.

1. Set up rest template to use `apache http client` -> `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'`
2. Updated my rest template bean to use httpclient -

   `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
   restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);`
3. Then just do what the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840639/spring-rest-template-with-http-client-for-ntlm-authentication) says. Add the `NtlmAuthenticator class` and do this just before your restTemplate call.

   `NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(userName, password);
   Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);`

That's it. You are all set up.

Comment: What did you do with the Authenticator? Can you post a full example?

Comment: How is the NtlmAuthenticator being used? Any purpose of that object?